# How to get directory contacts from gmail?

Tags: google-api, google-directory-api, google-people-api

I saw some of the posts to get directory contacts using contacts API implemented under **GData that is deprecated**. So is there any other way to get organization contacts via People API or Directory API for user?

I tried to get Organization contacts for user using Directory API based on the link. [Retrieve a user as a non-administrator](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#retrieve_users_non_admin)

I have done the steps mentioned in the below link :

[Turn the global Directory on or off](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60218)

Still i am getting following error.

```
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Not Authorized to access this resource/api",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Not Authorized to access this resource/api"
}
```

My Questions:

1. Can user get organization contacts under directory?
2. If yes, what Api need to use ?

Comment: Right now, you can't get directory contacts through Google People API.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Amos, any other ways?

Comment: I think GData might be the only way